# Showing proper balance ammount

Tags: mysql

I have a query where I suppose to show `debit`, `credit` & `balance`. I have no `balance` column in table. I calculate the balance from `debit` & `credit`.

I tried to create a balance column where balance will be stored and display it from table. But if I update or delete any row the balance will not proper.

I found the below code on SO. But it works when there is one row for a one date, multiple columns for a date is not working properly. It display the balance with day by day, I want to display balance with row by row.

**MySQL**

```
SELECT 
    m.`id`,
    m.`date`, 
    m.`credit`, 
    m.`debit`,
    SUM(t.`credit`) - SUM(t.`debit`) AS `balance`
FROM `cash_book` m 
    JOIN (
        SELECT 
            `id`,
            `date`,
            `credit`,
            `debit`
        FROM 
            `cash_book`
    ) t ON t.`date` <= m.`date`
WHERE `customer_id` = 1
GROUP BY 
    m.`id`
ORDER BY m.`date` ASC
```

It's return the result like this:

```
Date        Debit    Credit    Balance
2016-11-27      0      2000       2000
2016-12-02      0    500000     585000 //same result for date 2016-12-02
2016-12-02  15000         0     585000 //same result for date 2016-12-02
2016-12-02      0    100000     585000 //same result for date 2016-12-02
2016-12-03   1200         0     583800
2016-12-04   3160         0     580540 //same result for date 2016-12-04
2016-12-04    100         0     580540 //same result for date 2016-12-04
2016-12-05     30         0     580510
2016-12-06      0       150     580660
```

But I want the result like this:

```
Date        Debit    Credit    Balance
2016-11-27      0      2000       2000
2016-12-02      0    500000     502000 
2016-12-02  15000         0     487000 
2016-12-02      0    100000     587000 
2016-12-03   1200         0     585800
2016-12-04   3160         0     582640 
2016-12-04    100         0     582540 
2016-12-05     30         0     582510
2016-12-06      0       150     582660
```

Comment: pls also give the data so it'll be give you the solution

Comment: have your table also a unique id field ?

Comment: @BerndBuffen Yes. I have unique id field.

Comment: @kapil.dev I have posted the output result which is displaying the balance for a day.

Comment: @smartrahat - try this: change **) t ON t.`date` <= m.`date`** to **) t ON t.`date` <= m.`date` and t.id <= m.id**

Comment: @BerndBuffen The result is a mess. I can't figure out what it showing.

Comment: @smartrahat  - can you please post your table at http://sqlfiddle.com/ then i can rewrite the query

Comment: @BerndBuffen http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/efe125/6/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is it this what you looking for ?

```
SELECT 
    `id`,
    `date`,
    `credit`,
    `debit`,
    @balance := @balance + credit-debit AS balance
FROM `cash_book`
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @balance := 0) as init
ORDER BY `date` ASC ;
```

**sample**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM cash_book;
+------+------------+-------+--------+
| id   | date       | debit | credit |
+------+------------+-------+--------+
|    1 | 2016-11-27 |     0 |   2000 |
|    2 | 2016-12-04 |  3160 |      0 |
|    3 | 2016-12-02 | 15000 |      0 |
|    4 | 2016-12-03 |  1200 |      0 |
|    5 | 2016-12-05 |    30 |      0 |
|    6 | 2016-11-29 |     0 |  10000 |
|    7 | 2016-01-05 |     0 |      0 |
|    8 | 2016-12-01 |  2000 |      0 |
|    9 | 2016-11-29 | 10000 |      0 |
|   10 | 2016-12-02 |  2000 | 100000 |
|   11 | 2016-12-06 |  2000 |    150 |
|   12 | 2016-12-02 |  2000 | 500000 |
+------+------------+-------+--------+
12 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->     `id`,
    ->     `date`,
    ->     `credit`,
    ->     `debit`,
    ->     @balance := @balance + credit-debit AS balance
    -> FROM `cash_book`
    -> CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @balance := 0) as init
    -> ORDER BY `date` ASC ;
+------+------------+--------+-------+---------+
| id   | date       | credit | debit | balance |
+------+------------+--------+-------+---------+
|    7 | 2016-01-05 |      0 |     0 |       0 |
|    1 | 2016-11-27 |   2000 |     0 |    2000 |
|    6 | 2016-11-29 |  10000 |     0 |   12000 |
|    9 | 2016-11-29 |      0 | 10000 |    2000 |
|    8 | 2016-12-01 |      0 |  2000 |       0 |
|    3 | 2016-12-02 |      0 | 15000 |  -15000 |
|   10 | 2016-12-02 | 100000 |  2000 |   83000 |
|   12 | 2016-12-02 | 500000 |  2000 |  581000 |
|    4 | 2016-12-03 |      0 |  1200 |  579800 |
|    2 | 2016-12-04 |      0 |  3160 |  576640 |
|    5 | 2016-12-05 |      0 |    30 |  576610 |
|   11 | 2016-12-06 |    150 |  2000 |  574760 |
+------+------------+--------+-------+---------+
12 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you very much. Thanks all for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery in `select` part like this

```
SELECT 
    m.`id`,
    m.`date`, 
    m.`credit`, 
    m.`debit`,
    (select sum(n.`credit`) - sum(n.`debit`)
      from `cash_book` n
      where n.`id` = m.`id`
      and n.`date` <= m.`date`) balance
FROM `cash_book` m
WHERE `customer_id` = 1
ORDER BY m.`date` ASC
```

Comment: `#1054 - Unknown column 't.credit' in 'field list'`
Should I use this subquery inside the query?

Comment: Sorry, fixed it

Comment: The query is calculating with it's own row.

Comment: Is it not giving you proper result?

Comment: I need the balance of a customer's financial transaction. So, the previous transaction of the customer should be calculate too.

Comment: It *is* taking the previous transactions into account

Comment: Just try it and see if it gives you the right answer

Answer (score 0):

In your Query you have used `JOIN`, That will used to `join` two or more tables. Here you are using only one table. So no need of `JOIN` inside the query.

You can use this following simple query,

```
SELECT 
  m.id,
  m.date,
  m.credit,
  m.debit,
  (SELECT SUM(credit)-SUM(debit) 
     FROM`cash_book` A 
     WHERE A.date<=m.Date) 
FROM `cash_book` m WHERE m.customer_id = 1 ORDER BY m.Date ASC
```

Comment: The query is calculating with it's own row.

Comment: Yah, but the output will be same wish is want you

Comment: There is no `JOIN`

Comment: Yah, no need of Join

Comment: I need the balance of a customer's financial transaction. So, the previous transaction of the customer should be calculate too.

Comment: Using my query, it will happen

Comment: The problem is `WHERE A.id=m.id`, i thought that is customerid, just remove `A.id=m.id AND`

Comment: @K.Suthagar By removing this the result is same as my query

Comment: The problem for this, ID is not a in a order according to the date

Comment: use a auto increment id to check the order of the data, because you date haven't the time part, so we can not check properly

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
select s.Date,s.Debit,s.credit,ABS(@b := @b + s.debit - s.credit) as  balance from (select @b:= 0.0) as dummy cross join cash_book as s order by ID;
```